# Duplicate Contacts Displaying the Same Number but with Different Formatting

Tags: android, sqlite

I am relatively new to Android Development and I am currently in need of your help. In some devices, my code appears to work well, displaying no contacts with the same phone number (in a simple `ListView` of contact names and numbers). But when I tried it with other devices, I began to notice all contacts being duplicated, with the same phone numbers, but different number formatting.

For example, a contact name **Ana** would be displayed in the `ListView` twice with the numbers **09876543210** and **0987 654 3210**.

I tried searching everywhere here but I could not find any solution that fits my current situation. All solutions I found show deprecated and outdated code (not using the `CursorLoader`, using the deprecated `Contacts` instead of `ContactsContract`). I think the answer lies somewhere with the `ContactsContract` table, but I do not know much about it.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
public class ContactsTab extends ListFragment
    implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

ListView mContactsList;

// Defines an array from cursor column...
private static final String[] fromColumns = {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

// ...to views/rows (id)
private static final int[] toViews = {
        R.id.contactName,
        R.id.contactNumber
};

// An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
private ContactsSimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

// These are the contact rows to retrieve
private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

// This is the select criteria
private static final String SELECTION =
        "((" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " != ' ') AND ("
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1))";

private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 2;

private boolean mContactsPermissionGranted;
private boolean mCallPermissionGranted;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets cursor adapter
    mCursorAdapter = new ContactsSimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.contact_item_view,
            null,
            fromColumns,
            toViews,
            0);

    // Gets the ListView
    mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // starts the query
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC"
    );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Yunnosch How would this be possible also through CursorLoader?